# Image of the Gauss Map of Hyperboloid

Tags: differential-geometry

My problem states: Describe the region of the unit sphere covered by the image of the Gauss map of the hyperboloid of revolution $x^2+y^2-z^2=1$.

I first parametrized the hyperboloid as follows: 
$$x(u,v)=\sqrt{1+u^2}\cos(v)$$$$y(u,v)=\sqrt{1+u^2}\sin(v)$$$$z(u,v)=u$$ where $0\leq v < 2\pi$. Then, I want to compute the normal vector. I compute the partial derivatives 
$$\textbf{x}_u=\bigg(\frac{u}{\sqrt{1+u^2}}\cos(v),\frac{u}{\sqrt{1+u^2}}\sin(v),1\bigg)$$ and $$\textbf{x}_v=\bigg(-\sqrt{1+u^2}\sin(v), \sqrt{1+u^2}\cos(v),0\bigg)$$
I am unsure what to do next. I want to eventually get the coefficients of the first fundamental form, I believe. However, I'm not sure how to do so or what to do next.

Comment: The partials to a parameterization are like tangent vectors. Do you know a tool which eats two tangent vectors and returns a normal vector? Perhaps this tool is special to $\mathbb{R}^3$?

Comment: @AlfredYerger Cross product possibly?

Comment: Nice. You can normalize the result to get a point on the sphere.

Comment: @AlfredYerger so I want to compute the cross product of $\textbf{x}_u$ and $\textbf{x}_v$, then divide by the magnitude of the cross product? this will give a point on the sphere and that's the image of the gauss map?

Comment: Correct. A unit normal can be identified with the point on the sphere with the same normal. But the normal to a point on the sphere has the same coordinates as the point itself.

Comment: @AlfredYerger I have calculated the unit normal, but it is still in terms of $u$ and $v$. Won't I want it to be integer values to represent a point on the unit sphere?